# What is the optimal length of time for pulling a shot of espresso?

Tags: brewing-process, espresso

Assuming:

- The beans are ground correctly, and are of good quality
- You have the right amount of grind in the basket
- The grounds are tamped correctly
- The machine is set to the correct temperature (90°C to 96°C (195°F to 205°F))

First: is there an optimal length of time for a shot of espresso to be pulled for highest quality taste and aroma? If so, for how long?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That will completely depend on the blend of espresso you are using.  Different coffees will have different pull times.

In my experience as a barista, you'll aim for about 28 seconds on most shots.  Some of the blends we've used aimed more at 25 to 31 seconds.

TL;DR: Depends on the coffee.